# More Laplace! - help needed

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Here is the exam question that I am practicing:

[image]

I have completed the first two parts to this question (thankfully to stackexchange)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468596/laplace-question-help-needed/468600?noredirect=1#comment1008905_468600

[Laplace question continued (partial fractions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468851/laplace-question-continued-partial-fractions/468916?noredirect=1#468916)

With regards to the third part, I am confused as to how to approach it. Do I need to find the inverse using partial fractions?

I have been stuck on this for a very long time and any sort of help is hugely hugely appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the third part, note that we know that: $$\mathcal{L}(t)=\frac{1}{s^2},~~\mathcal{L}(\cos t)=\frac{s}{s^2+1},~~\mathcal{L}(\sin t)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$ so $$x(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(X(s))=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-3\frac{1}{s^2+1}\right)=t+\cos t-3\sin t$$

Comment: Helpful, as always! +1

Comment: @Babak My lovely Transform after Fourier one! +1

Answer (score 1):

For an initial value problem, don't forget to incorporate the initial values into the Laplace transform!

$$\mathcal{x''}=s^2X(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)$$

The differential equation is transformed into the Laplace domain as follows:

$$\mathcal{L}(x'')+\mathcal{L}(x)=\mathcal{L}(t)\\
s^2X(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)+X(s)=\mathcal{L}(t)$$

The partial fraction decomposition makes it possible to do an inverse Laplace transform to go back to time domain using known [elementary Laplace transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms).